# what does 'I would have killed with this crowd' means?

Tags: meaning

I saw that in modern family S1. and I've never heard about 'kill with'. kill crowd? kill with crowd? are they different?

Comment: Not seen it. Your post is rather thin, but it could mean "I would have killed [if I had been] with this crowd."

Comment: It seems to be a (very slangy) way of saying *I would have been **a tremendous hit*** (where *I would have [**smashed it***](https://blog.busuu.com/10-british-expressions/#:~:text=Smash%20it!,Smash%20it!%E2%80%9D.), or ***...slaughtered the competition*** would be "figuratively similar" equally slangy alternatives). I don't know the series, but I see the preceding line (in the subtitle file that I just checked out) is ***Look at these queens!*** Might this be a couple of young gays out on the town looking to be picked up and wined & dined by richer "old queens"?

Comment: What FumbleFingers said -- basically a variation on https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/kill-it

Comment: *Killing it* is a very common slang phrase. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=killin+it&atb=v245-1&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: thanks for you guy's comments!! so, is it okay that either 'kill with this crowd' or 'kill this crowd'?

Comment: @bishop2 "killing this crowd" without a context could literally mean "killing people"

Answer (score 3):

It means he [would have done something extremely successfully](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kill-it) if he knew this particular crowd would be there, around him, or watching him.

You can say

> That comedian kills me.

if you find them funny and they make you laugh all the time.

Comment: I gave you thumbs up. There are other possible shades of meaning. For example, the crowd might be very easy to please. Or the crowd might be such as to produce virtue in the speaker. It is a show about family so maybe it means if he had been raised by them he would have turned out brilliant.